# Starling/Flash Builder - "Waiting to connect to the running application..."

Tags: flash, flash-builder, starling-framework

I've been trying to run a simple starling test that only traces out some text. When I debug, the progress bar stops at 57% and i get the message "Launching: Waiting to connect to the running application...". It stays like this for a few minutes and then I get the error

"Launch Failed

The Flash Builder debugger failed to connect to the running application.
Ensure that:

1. For in-browser applications, you are running the debugger version of Flash Player.
2. For network debugging on a mobile device, you have a reliable network connection to the device, and port 7935 is open on your machine's firewall."

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling flash player/debugger several times, checked my localhosts for duplicates, and upgraded the Air SDK, but still no luck.

Comment: Do you have the debugger version of the flash player for the environment your application runs on? Also, did you alter the path where your files are run?

Comment: What browser are you using?  I know that Chrome and IE for Windows 8 use a built-in version of Flash, and that there are tricks to get them to use the debug version.  You can verify if the debug Flash player is installed by checking the version at http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html and selecting "Check Now"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to debug to web, so InteliJ is waiting for your browser to open and launch your application, however it needs **Flash Debugger** installed, just go to Flash Download site and scroll down and download your OS version of it.